# Angular 6, ng-busy: How can I apply the ng-busy animation to a button?

Tags: javascript, angular, loading

I've been battling this ng-busy for a couple of days as I have been trying to learn Angular.

I have this plunker page that has it kind of working but not as I want.
The page is displaying the loading animation but I want to have it display the loading animation within the button and not over the whole area.

Can someone direct me to where I can find real information that explains how to use this thing. The ng-busy npm page is not working for me in really learning this.

[My attempt at animated loading ng-busy](https://angular-cudkrg.stackblitz.io)

[image: Plunker loading not on button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this ng-busy package is not made to put it inside a button.

I would suggest to place a spinner inside the button and display or hide it with *ngIf. If you are working with Promises or Observables you can use the *ngIf with the async pipe.

```
<button mat-button>Basic<mat-spinner *ngIf='showSpinner'></mat-spinner></button>
<button mat-button>Basic <mat-spinner *ngIf='showSpinnerPromise | async'></mat-spinner></button>
```

Comment: Simon, the original code in the application I am put on to work was utilizing ngif conditions on a <i> tag with a spinner class. I was instructed to replace the current animated stuff with the ng-busy. I thought there would have been something that I am missing but based on what you are saying I should pretty much just modify the ngBusy to use its onBusyStart and onBusyStop to control the ngif vars for animating and not animating. This just seems like a hack. Am I missing something here or is this just how it is when using these packages from NPM?

Comment: what is your real intent to do?
You need to control the ng-busy as well by providing a Promise or an Observable. 
So using onBusyStart and onBusyStop to control another variable to control another element with *ngIf is just redundant. 

This is not directly connected with NPM packages. Anyone can publish NPM packages, It's on you to choose the right package that is solving your problem.

Comment: Being that this is new to me I'm more under the impression that the packages are containing features that I would just expect to be in them. So, I thought the ng-busy package was intended for the purpose of indicating the start and completion of observing a call. Something that would have been truly generic to be able to just apply the loading template to any element. It seems to me that the package is not even required as I could just utilize the method I call to set a variable and a promise so upon completion set the variable again to turn off the animated feature of the loading style.

Comment: Yep, I would recommend to go the straight way :) 
ng-busy is intended to indicate the start and completion of a call. But with a global indicator. It also solves some other issues you will get when you are working with many parallel requests. 
But for one request and with a certain style in mind the direct way with *ngIf is much leaner.